# How to preserve key where multiple joins are used?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

In the code below I have created a view table that is used for displaying staff related data. For each staff I need to get all columns from staff as well as "dept_title" from "department" table and "unit_title" from "unit" table. Basically I have LEFT JOINED "staff" table with the result from INNER JOINING "unit" table with "unit_staff" staff table("unit_staff" is a junction table between unit and staff).The result from joining these three tables is LEFT JOINED with the "department" table. So now I have all the different columns from three different tables in the same view.

( **staff**-----*left join*-----> ( **unit**-----*Inner join*----->**unit_staff** ) ) -----*left join*----->**department**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_STAFF" (
    "STAFF_ID", 
    "STAFF_NAME",
    "SALUTATION",
    "GENDER", 
    "CONTACT_NO", 
    "PRIMARY_EMAIL", 
    "SECONDARY_EMAIL", 
    "DOB", "ADDRESS", 
    "NATIONALITY", 
    "STAFF_TYPE", 
    "DEPT_NAME",
    "UNITS_NAME"
) AS 
SELECT staff.staff_id, 
staff.staff_name,
staff.salutation,
staff.gender,
staff.contact_no,
staff.primary_email,
staff.secondary_email,
staff.dob,
staff.address,
staff.nationality,
staff.staff_type,
department.dept_title,
LISTAGG(unit_title, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY unit_title) AS units
FROM (staff
LEFT JOIN (unit_staff INNER JOIN unit ON unit_staff.unit_id = unit.unit_id)
ON staff.staff_id = unit_staff.staff_id) LEFT JOIN department ON staff.dept_id = department.dept_id
GROUP BY staff.staff_id, 
staff.staff_name,
staff.salutation,
staff.gender,
staff.contact_no,
staff.primary_email,
staff.secondary_email,
staff.dob,
staff.address,
staff.nationality,
staff.staff_type,
department.dept_title;
/
```

The problem is that the key isn't preserved in the view. Before, I hadn't include the "department" table in the view and I had no problem with key preservation while inserting data. So I thought that adding "department" table which has one to one relationship will not break the key preservation, but it did. I think the problem is with the way I am grouping the different columns. How can I make changes to the above code so that the key will be preserved?

Comment: The most important part here are the constraints on the tables. Oracle determines if the key would be preserved by ensuring your attempt matches the relevant PK/FK constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that removing the aggregation and using subqueries will solve the problem:

```
select s.*,
       (select listagg(u.unit_title, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY unit_title) AS units
        from unit_staff us join
             unit u 
             on us.unit_id = u.unit_id
        where s.staff_id = us.staff_id)
       ) as units,
       (select d.dept_title
        from department d
        where s.dept_id = d.dept_id
       ) as dept_tital
from staff s;
```